# Drupal 7 error when using Redis on AWS causing error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, redis, drupal-7

We are using Redis with Drupal 7 on AWS servers. But after adding the php-redis PHP extension, the Redis contrib module and the configuration (as defined in the contrib module README) in the settings.php file, we are getting the following error when doing a cache clear (drush cc all):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/module.inc:763
Stack trace:
#0 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/module.inc(963): module_implements()
#1 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/modules/system/system.module(2522): module_invoke_all()
#2 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/theme.inc(798): _system_rebuild_theme_data()
#3 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(57): list_themes()
#4 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/bootstrap.inc(2945): _drupal_maintenance_theme()
#5 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/errors.inc(177): drupal_maintenance_theme()
#6 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/bootstrap.inc(2670): _drupal_log_error()
#7 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler()
#8 {main}
  thrown in DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/module.inc on line 763
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]
Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in
DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/module.inc:763
Stack trace:
#0 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/module.inc(963):
module_implements()
#1 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/modules/system/system.module(2522):
module_invoke_all()
#2 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/theme.inc(798):
_system_rebuild_theme_data()
#3 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(57):
list_themes()
#4 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/bootstrap.inc(2945):
_drupal_maintenance_theme()
#5 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/errors.inc(177):
drupal_maintenance_theme()
#6 DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/bootstrap.inc(2670):
_drupal_log_error()
#7 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler()
#8 {main}
  thrown in DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/includes/module.inc, line 763
```

Has anyone ever seen this type of thing with Drupal 7 and Redis implementation on AWS? Oddly, this only occurs on our AWS staging instance. The same implementation on a dev instance with the exact same configuration works fine.

We've tried ssl and non-ssl Redis connections. And compared both environments, which are configured exactly the same. Also verified the connection between the Drupal server and Redis server with the cli Redis client.

Comment: Are you using the same PHP version on both the environments?

Comment: yes, same PHP, Drupal versions and code.